# Treatment for severe Pain

Tags: medications, eye, treatment

I've been having severe internal pain around my eye, why? And how can it be taken care of

Comment: If I could get the name of this pain, it would be really helpful

Comment: It is difficult to make a correct diagnose over the internet. If you are experiencing severe pain, you should see your doctor ASAP. Best of luck!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firstly what you are going through is called cluster headache.   https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_headache.                                                                                        Secondly, three main treatments are available to relieve pain when taken soon after a cluster headache starts. These are: sumatriptan injections, which you can give yourself up to twice a day. sumatriptan or zolmitriptan nasal spray, which can be used if you would prefer not to have injections.        http://www.nhs.uk/conditions/cluster-headaches/Pages/Introduction.aspx

Comment: Diagnosing a cluster headache without exam, medical history, and a bunch of other information is very dangerous.  Maybe the question was different when you originally answered it.  But if he had cellulitis or glaucoma or another medical emergency, a narrow answer could have left him thinking he didn't need to be evaluated, and if it were a condition needing immediate therapy, he could have lost an eyeball or worse.  Although your information on cluster headaches is accurate, this is an example of why medical advice questions are strictly off topic.